# SQL: Select Rows if a Condition is Met Throughout an ID

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table:

```
  id  color    food
1  1    red cookies
2  1   blue   pizza
3  1  green    cake
4  2    red   pasta
5  2    red    cake
6  2    red cookies
7  3   blue   pizza
8  3  green   pizza
9  3 yellow   pizza
```

**My Question:** If a given ID ever contained the values "red" and "pizza" (does not have to be in the same row) - I want to select all rows for that ID.

In my example, only the rows for ID=1 would be selected:

```
# Expected Results
  id  color    food
1  1    red cookies
2  1   blue   pizza
3  1  green    cake
```

I thought that perhaps this could be done with the IN statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE (color = 'red' OR food = 'pizza') 
);
```

But this is returning the original table.

**Can someone please show me how to do this?**

Thanks!

**Note:** Here is the data used to generate the table

```
my_table = (
id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
color = c("red", "blue", "green", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow"),
food = c("cookies", "pizza", "cake", "pasta", "cake", "cookies", "pizza", "pizza", "pizza")
)
```

Comment: Your query would return the whole table because ID 1 & 2 are having colour as red and id is having food as pizza. What result you are expecting and why?

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to solve this, but one easy way is to find all the "red" ids, and all the "pizza" ids and intersect them (inner join)

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE id IN (
    (SELECT distinct id From my_table
     Where color = 'red') red Inner Join
    (SELECT distinct id From my_table
     WHERE food='pizza') pizza On red.id=pizza.id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For two criterua you cn use EXISTS and for evey other condition,  you need another EXISTS

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table t1
WHERE (color = 'red')
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHER id = t1.ied AND  food = 'pizza') 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about conditional aggregation (to decide `ID`) and then fetch rows that belong to it?

Sample data:

```
         1 COLOR  FOOD
---------- ------ -------
         1 red    cookies
         1 blue   pizza
         1 green  cake
         2 red    pasta
         2 red    cake
         2 red    cookies
         3 blue   pizza
         3 green  pizza
         3 yellow pizza
```

Query:

```
   select a.*
   from test a
   where exists (select null
                 from test b
                 where b.id = a.id
                 group by b.id
                 having sum(case when b.color = 'red'  then 1 else 0 end) > 0
                    and sum(case when b.food = 'pizza' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
                );

        ID COLOR  FOOD
---------- ------ -------
         1 green  cake
         1 blue   pizza
         1 red    cookies

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `GROUP BY` id and check both color = red and food = pizza occur at least once in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM my_table
GROUP BY
  id
HAVING
  COUNT(CASE WHEN color = 'red' THEN 1 END) > 0
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN food = 'pizza' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

If the whole row is required rather just the id, write an outer query and use `IN` or `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
  id, color, food 
FROM my_table
  WHERE id IN
(SELECT
  id
FROM my_table
GROUP BY
  id
HAVING
  COUNT(CASE WHEN color = 'red' THEN 1 END) > 0
  AND COUNT(CASE WHEN food = 'pizza' THEN 1 END) > 0);
```

Here a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SKAppfM8) based on your sample data (I know the fiddle is Postgres, but afaik, this will also work in Netezza).